# Speeding up a query to SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have done some measurements regarding the IO on my SQLite database. It takes around 6 seconds to load some object from this database. I have a class which extends Asynctask, this class job is to load the last 10 entries in my database. This class is constructed this way:

```
import View.CustomAdapter;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;

public class LoadCases extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<Case>> {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ArrayList<Case> lastTenCases; 
    CustomAdapter cAdapter; 
    Context context;
    ListView lastCases;
    DatabaseHandler db;
    TextView loading;
    int options;

    public LoadCases(ProgressBar progressBar, Context context, ListView lastCases, TextView loading, ArrayList<Case> lastTenCases) {
        this.progressBar = progressBar;
        this.context = context;
        this.lastCases = lastCases;
        this.loading = loading;
        this.lastTenCases = lastTenCases;
        db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    }

    public void onPreExecute() {
        progressBar.incrementProgressBy(1);
    }


    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Case> doInBackground(String... params) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        lastTenCases = db.getAllCases(10);
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        Log.d("TIME TO LOAD CASES FROM BASE: ", Long.toString((end-start)/1000000000)); 
        return lastTenCases;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Case> result) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        cAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, lastTenCases);    
        cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        lastCases.setAdapter(cAdapter);
```

}
}

As you may see, the measurements is done just before I call the method `getAllCases(10)`

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
lastTenCases = db.getAllCases(10);
long end = System.nanoTime();
Log.d("TIME TO LOAD CASES FROM BASE: ", Long.toString((end-start)/1000000000));
```

This will give me about 6 seconds to load 10 cases from the database, as I mentioned earlier.

Now, over to the `getAllCases` method

```
public ArrayList<Case> getAllCases(int take) {

    ArrayList<Case> caseList = new ArrayList<Case>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  *, (strftime('%s', DATE) * 1000) AS DATENOW FROM " + TABLE_CASES + " ORDER BY " + DATE + " DESC LIMIT " + Integer.toString(take) + " ;";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Case c = new Case();

            long millis = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("DATENOW"));
            Date addedOn = new Date(millis);
            c.setCaseNumber(cursor.getString(0));
            c.setDate(addedOn.toLocaleString());
            c.setStatus(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(STATUS)));
            caseList.add(c);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return caseList;
}
```

This method will construct `Case` objects, and add this to an `ArrayList`. This ArrayList will be return. Yeah, I guess you understand the code. But 6 seconds, really? What am I doing wrong? How can I speed up this operation?

Thanks!

Comment: to begin, why do you select DATENOW if you know it basically is the same for all rows and can be a simple System.currentTimeMillis() ?

Comment: then, i suggest you write a code that does all that a lot and use traceview to see what is so slow

Comment: also, it appears you are selecting * while you only need _id and STATUS (which column index you could get only once). Plus, rawQuery is not the recommended method. query is better.

Comment: This is because when I'm adding the object to the database, I also adds a date. This date was not the correct timezone, after spending hours at google, I found that solution.

Comment: finally, Debug.startMethodTracing and stopMethodTracing will help you track bottlenecks (see http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#profiling )

Comment: doesn't make sense. you are creating a strftime object for each row, i would guess that's not very efficient. (try to remove it to see if it works any better). Also, if you are on an asyncTask, you may have a low priority

Comment: Thank u @njzk2! I'm guessing that the `*` in my query causes the problems, because there are two blobs files in my base.. These blobs will on the other hand be loaded when the user presses an item from my `ListView`

Comment: also your DATE is a string and is parsed for each row. that's really not efficient. you need to store dates as longs without timezone (Date.getTime()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on Your database structure (e.g. if TABLE_CASES is just another complex query) and number of fields in `TABLE_CASES`, but at least the following points might be improved:

- `strftime('%s', DATE) * 1000)` - do You really need to calculate it every time when You need to get CASE? Storing of that value instead of calculation will definitely speed up the query;
- Not sure if ArrayList needed, probably [CursorLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) could be used;
- Based on [this tip](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation) calling of `new Date(millis)` probably should be moved out of the loop;
- Calls to `getColumnIndexOrThrow` and `getColumnIndex` should be also moved out of the loop;
- `toLocaleString` is deprecated in API level 1 please use [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Finally, I would suggest to follow [this guide for traceview](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) and determine if the delay actually happens in SQLite or in the loop just after it.